# Indy always returns ResponseCode 200 - even for a failed login

Tags: delphi, authentication, delphi-xe, indy10

I'm using Indy 10.5.7

I've recently been shown how to use Indy to login into a website with valid credentials. Now I can perform searches and return the results I need.

However, I still have a problem. I have to take for granted that I am logged in successfully based on a page redirect as I am unable to get a response code other than 200.

What I mean is, I would like to handle a situation where a user enters a typo in either the username or password, and at least inform them that something is amiss.

For the sake of this question, I have set Indy up as follows ...

```
var
  client      : TidHTTP;
  cookieMan   : TidCookieManager;
  params      : TStringList;
  response    : string;

begin
  cookieMan := TidCookieManager.Create(nil);
  client := TidHTTP.Create(nil);
  params := TStringList.Create;

  try
    with client do
    begin
      ProtocolVersion     := pv1_1;
      HTTPOptions         := [hoForceEncodeParams, hoKeepOrigProtocol];
      AllowCookies        := True;
      cookieManager       := cookieMan;
      HandleRedirects     := True;
      //Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0';
      //Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64)  AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.103 Safari/537.36';
      Request.UserAgent   := 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i586; en-US; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20040924 Epiphany/1.4.4 (Ubuntu)';
      //OnRedirect          := handleRedirect;
    end;

    params.Add('username=aFakeUser');
    params.Add('password=aFakePass');

    try
      response := client.Post('http://assurance.redtractor.org.uk/rtassurance/services.eb', params);
      mmoResponseCodes.Lines.Add('No exception, INDY OK ' + intToStr(client.ResponseCode));         // << ALWAYS returns 200
      // do nothing with params ...  just to try to raise any exception

      // I need to be logged in to reach the next page, this is a search page ...
      response := client.Post('http://assurance.redtractor.org.uk/rtassurance/services/cr_services/checking.eb', params);
      mmoResponseCodes.Lines.Add('Still no exception, INDY OK ' + intToStr(client.ResponseCode));   // << ALWAYS returns 200
      mmoResponse.Text := response;

    except
      on e: EIdHTTPProtocolException do
      begin
        // No exception raised, I expected e.ErrorCode = 401
        mmoResponseCodes.Lines.Add('Post Indy Error ' + intToStr(e.ErrorCode) + ' >>> ' + e.Message);
      end;
    end;

  finally
    client.Free;
    cookieMan.Free;
    params.Free;
  end;
end;
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong. I've seen lots of posts by Remy pointing out to catch exceptions and look at the e.ErrorCode, but I just can't raise an exception with my deliberately fake credentials.

May I ask you point me in the right direction please, and point out what I have done wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using **HTML-based authentication** (a posted HTML webform), not **HTTP-based authentication** (the HTTP `Authentication` request header).

From an HTTP standpoint, a failed authentication of an HTML webform can still be reported as a successful 200 reply at the HTTP layer. The client requested a URL and the server delivered an HTML page in reply. Whether the HTML claims authentication was successful or failed is irrelevant, HTTP is just a transport, it doesn't care about the particular content being delivered. An HTTP error is only reported if an HTTP-layer error occurs. If HTML authentication fails, the resulting HTML page will usually contain an error message, and/or the login HTML webform again.

So, in this case, you are getting an HTTP 200 reply because HTTP did its job successfully. You will have to analyze the actual HTML being returned to know whether the authentication really succeeded or failed.  There is no indication one way or the other at the HTTP layer.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response. Mmm, I'm afraid I've shown my weakness in web technology ... HTML ... HTTP ... until your post, they were one and the same to me. I'll read the HTML for errors.

Comment: Back in the early days of the Internet, HTTP (Hyper-Text Transport Protocol) was originally designed to carry only HTML (Hyper-Text Markup Language), but it has evolved over the years into something so much more. HTML is only one of many many data formats that HTTP carries in modern Internet systems.

Comment: Thank you again, Remy, your answer here ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076775/how-to-clear-the-indy-tidhttp-basicauthentication-credentials helped me get a 401. I just need to play and learn now.

Comment: What about the `Not Found` error pages? When you try to reach a non existent URL, many web applications return a 404 HTTP status code along with some custom HTML for showing an error message. It is not a similar scenario? After your explanation, I guess a 200 status code would be acceptable too, but everybody sends the 404.

Comment: @JoanBotella no, it is not a similar situation. Requesting a URL that does not exist is an HTTP error. 404 is specifically defined in the HTTP spec for that purpose. There is nothing defined in the HTTP spec for HTML webform errors. The server *could* use something like 500, if it wanted to. But really, like I said in my answer, failure to authenticate over HTML is not an HTTP error, so 200 is more appropriate at the HTTP layer.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I see your point, but I think it's a little confusing. After all, is the web application who responds the 404, not the web server. You could say that all the URLs that can be processed by the application do exist, and therefore, should return 200. I think this 404 case is especial, because warning search engines not to index the URL is critical.